# How to Export a Function from a C++ Header File

Tags: c++, oop, export

I am working on an assignment in my Object Oriented Programming class. One of the many instructions in the assignment was to take some of the teacher's code and break it into different modules/files. The instructions goes as follows:

***The joblist module, consisting of the files joblist.cpp and joblist.hpp, should contain the global variables threshold and jobs, as well as the functions firstJobMeetingThreshold, removeJob, addJob, hasJob, and getJob. However, only the threshold variable and the addJob, hasJob, and getJob functions should be exported from this module. The remaining variables and functions are there as helpers.***

I have the following code in my header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int threshold;
vector<Job> jobs;

int firstJobMeetingThreshold();
void removeJob(int i);
void addJob(Job job);
bool hasJob();
Job getJob();
```

(Job is an object from another class that does not need to be worried about)

The part that I am confused about with the assignment is how to make the specific functions exported and to how to make the others helpers. The functions are not supposed to be moved into another class or anything, so I am to go about this?

I am sorry if my instructions are unclear, I will provide any needed clarification. I am very new to OOP so I am still trying to figure out a lot of these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding variables, you should add `export` before their declaration, for the ones you want to share with other source files. Specifically in your case, in the header file you should have

```
export int threshold;
```

To limit the functions scope, do you want to introduce a namespace? Otherwise you could remove the helper functions' declaration from the header file. If you do the latter, make sure that you define them in the source file before the first time you need to call them.

Answer (score 0):

source => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-c-functions-for-use-in-c-or-cpp-language-executables?view=msvc-170

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {  // only need to export C interface if
              // used by C++ source code
#endif

__declspec( dllimport ) void MyCFunc();
__declspec( dllimport ) void AnotherCFunc();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32264621)